# Add notes on Geany

Tags: programming, text-editor, editor, geany, notes

I have a code to which I do not like to add my comments and notes. But I need the ability to add my notes on that. So is there any thing to do that on Geany or do you need any another editor to do that?

Comment: I keep my notes in a separate application. In my case it's Tomboy. Does it need to be integrated in the Text-Editor? Tomboy can link to file resources on your harddisk...

Comment: @MadMike if the IDE has this ability that will be cooler . But not restrict to that . please add your answer. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emacs has an [annotation mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/OrgAnnotateFile) that you may want to explore.

I haven't used emacs in the past 6+ years, so cannot give you specific directions, but, google should help.